# How can I get PreMailer.Net to not change the encoding of non-ascii characters?

Tags: html, css, premailer

I've also posted my problem as a [Github Issue](https://github.com/milkshakesoftware/PreMailer.Net/issues/193) on the official repo.

I am using [PreMailer.Net](https://github.com/milkshakesoftware/PreMailer.Net) to inline CSS into HTML documents. However, when I call MoveCssInline, it encodes non-ASCII characters like '&'. For example:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/page?param1=a&param2=b"></a>
```

Is changed to:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/page?param1=a&amp;param2=b"></a>
```

I thought this behavior would be limited to URLs and href values but it turns out it also encodes innerHTML/content. For instance:

Additionally, I have tested further and found that this encoding is not just done on attributes like href. It in fact will also encode text/InnerHTML values, which are absolutely valid html without encoding. Example:

```
<p>&</p>
```

This is valid HTML and should not be encoded, but PreMailer.Net will change this to:

```
<p>&amp;</p>
```

Does anyone have a fix or workaround for this? I do not have control over the HTML documents and am not allowed to change the URLs or content other than inlining the CSS.

Comment: Would encodeURIComponent and decodeURIComponent work for this purpose.
References if needed
<hr>
[Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) [Decoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) (Assuming you have access to JavaScript)

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 - I do not have access to JavaScript, this is all running server-side in an ASP.NET / C# environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your individual needs, as merely a guide, try these:

```
        Symbols.Ampersand: temp.Append("&amp;")
        Symbols.NoBreakSpace: temp.Append("&nbsp;")
        Symbols.GreaterThan: temp.Append("&gt;")
        Symbols.LessThan: temp.Append("&lt;")
```

Update:

These lines come from lines [132-139](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/blob/master/src/AngleSharp/Html/HtmlMarkupFormatter.cs#L132) of a PreMailer.Net dependency called [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp), which is an HTML parser.

Currently, as far as I can tell the encoding is mandatory on AngleSharp, and hence it cannot be avoided with any setting in either AngleSharp or PreMailer.Net.

According to the following [closed issue](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/348#issuecomment-221334825), this is by design in accordance with the HTML spec. However, I believe there is still a bug as it should only encode attribute values, not innerHTML content. Additionally, I don't think it is an acceptable behavior for a CSS inliner, which should not be validating or sanitizing HTML. Additionally, I don't even think the parser should be making changes that are not asked for by the client.

Comment: Okay, where/how would I use those though?

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/blob/master/src/AngleSharp/Html/HtmlMarkupFormatter.cs

Comment: Actually, that looks very promising. I commented out some of those lines and it looks like it might fix my problem, assuming it doesn't have other undesirable side effects.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been discussed over [here](https://github.com/premailer/premailer/issues/30) and fixed [here](https://github.com/premailer/premailer/pull/181).

You should use these options as mentioned in [this](https://github.com/premailer/premailer/blob/master/lib/premailer/premailer.rb) file.

```
:input_encoding => 'ASCII-8BIT',
:output_encoding => nil,
```

Comment: All of those are for Premailer - the Ruby implementation. I'm using PreMailer.Net, and it doesn't appear to have those options.